# Google Oauth 2 using flask_googlelogin

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, flask

Hello Stackoveflow members

I am making a Google Plus user authentication using Oauth and at the same time I need to fetch user profile, pics and drive information as well. The best way to do this is to use Oauth. So I am using [flask_googlelogin](https://github.com/insynchq/flask-googlelogin).

I am trying to use the example.py of this library but What I found that the API works well and my Application pages comes up with information and Cancel and Accept button. But when I push accept button, I get the flask error

TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Now please have a look at the example.py code and flask_googlelogin.py code

here

```
import json

from flask import Flask, url_for, redirect, session

from flask_login import (UserMixin, login_required, login_user, logout_user,
                     current_user)
from flask_googlelogin import GoogleLogin


users = {}


app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.update(
    SECRET_KEY='<secret_key>',
    GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_ID='<client_id>',
    GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_SECRET='<client_secret>',
    GOOGLE_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URI='<redirection_url>')
googlelogin = GoogleLogin(app)


class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, userinfo):
        self.id = userinfo['id']
        self.name = userinfo['name']
        self.picture = userinfo.get('picture')


@googlelogin.user_loader
def get_user(userid):
    return users.get(userid)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return """
        <p><a href="%s">Login</p>
        <p><a href="%s">Login with extra params</p>
        <p><a href="%s">Login with extra scope</p>
    """ % (
        googlelogin.login_url(approval_prompt='force'),
        googlelogin.login_url(approval_prompt='force',
                          params=dict(extra='large-fries')),
        googlelogin.login_url(
            approval_prompt='force',
            scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
            access_type='offline',
        ),
    )


@app.route('/profile')
@login_required
def profile():
    return """
        <p>Hello, %s</p>
        <p><img src="%s" width="100" height="100"></p>
        <p>Token: %r</p>
        <p>Extra: %r</p>
        <p><a href="/logout">Logout</a></p>
        """ % (current_user.name, current_user.picture, session.get('token'),
               session.get('extra'))


@app.route('/oauth2callback')
@googlelogin.oauth2callback
def login(token, userinfo, **params):
    user = users[userinfo['id']] = User(userinfo)
    login_user(user)
    session['token'] = json.dumps(token)
    session['extra'] = params.get('extra')
    return redirect(params.get('next', url_for('.profile')))


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    session.clear()
    return """
        <p>Logged out</p>
        <p><a href="/">Return to /</a></p>
        """


app.run(debug=True)
```

and flask_googlelogin.py code here

```
"""
Flask-GoogleLogin
"""

from base64 import (urlsafe_b64encode as b64encode,
                    urlsafe_b64decode as b64decode)
from urllib import urlencode
from urlparse import parse_qsl
from functools import wraps

from flask import request, redirect, abort, current_app, url_for
from flask_login import LoginManager, make_secure_token

import requests


GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_URL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth'
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_USERINFO_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo'
USERINFO_PROFILE_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'


class GoogleLogin(object):
    """
    Main extension class
    """

    def __init__(self, app=None, login_manager=None):
        if login_manager:
            self.login_manager = login_manager
        else:
            self.login_manager = LoginManager()

        if app:
            self._app = app
            self.init_app(app)

    def init_app(self, app, add_context_processor=True, login_manager=None):
        """
        Initialize with app configuration. Existing
       `flask_login.LoginManager` instance can be passed.
        """

        if login_manager:
            self.login_manager = login_manager
        else:
            self.login_manager = LoginManager()

        # Check if login manager has been init
        if not hasattr(app, 'login_manager'):
            self.login_manager.init_app(
                app,
                add_context_processor=add_context_processor)

        # Clear flashed messages since we redirect to auth immediately
        self.login_manager.login_message = None
        self.login_manager.needs_refresh_message = None

        # Set default unauthorized callback
        self.login_manager.unauthorized_handler(self.unauthorized_callback)

    @property
    def app(self):
        return getattr(self, '_app', current_app)

    @property
    def scopes(self):
        return self.app.config.get('GOOGLE_LOGIN_SCOPES', '')

    @property
    def client_id(self):
        return self.app.config['GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_ID']

    @property
    def client_secret(self):
        return self.app.config['GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_SECRET']

    @property
    def redirect_uri(self):
        return self.app.config.get('GOOGLE_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URI')

    @property
    def redirect_scheme(self):
        return self.app.config.get('GOOGLE_LOGIN_REDIRECT_SCHEME', 'http')

    def sign_params(self, params):
        return b64encode(urlencode(dict(sig=make_secure_token(**params),
                                    **params)))

    def parse_state(self, state):
        return dict(parse_qsl(b64decode(str(state))))

    def login_url(self, params=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Return login url with params encoded in state

        Available Google auth server params:
        response_type: code, token
        prompt: none, select_account, consent
        approval_prompt: force, auto
        access_type: online, offline
        scopes: string (separated with commas) or list
        redirect_uri: string
        login_hint: string
        """
        kwargs.setdefault('response_type', 'code')
        kwargs.setdefault('access_type', 'online')

        if 'prompt' not in kwargs:
            kwargs.setdefault('approval_prompt', 'auto')

        scopes = kwargs.pop('scopes', self.scopes.split(','))
        if USERINFO_PROFILE_SCOPE not in scopes:
            scopes.append(USERINFO_PROFILE_SCOPE)

        redirect_uri = kwargs.pop('redirect_uri', self.redirect_uri)
        state = self.sign_params(params or {})

        return GOOGLE_OAUTH2_AUTH_URL + '?' + urlencode(
            dict(client_id=self.client_id,
                  scope=' '.join(scopes),
                 redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
                 state=state,
                 **kwargs))
    def unauthorized_callback(self):
        """
        Redirect to login url with next param set as request.url
        """
        return redirect(self.login_url(params=dict(next=request.url)))

    def exchange_code(self, code, redirect_uri):
        """
        Exchanges code for token/s
        """

        token = requests.post(GOOGLE_OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL, data=dict(
            code=code,
            redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
            grant_type='authorization_code',
            client_id=self.client_id,
            client_secret=self.client_secret,
        )).json
        if not token: # or token.get('error'):
            abort(400)
        return token

    def get_userinfo(self, access_token):
        userinfo = requests.get(GOOGLE_OAUTH2_USERINFO_URL, params=dict(
            access_token=access_token,
        )).json
        if not userinfo: # or userinfo.get('error'):
            abort(400)
        return userinfo

    def get_access_token(self, refresh_token):
        """
        Use a refresh token to obtain a new access token
        """

        token = requests.post(GOOGLE_OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL, data=dict(
            refresh_token=refresh_token,
            grant_type='refresh_token',
            client_id=self.client_id,
            client_secret=self.client_secret,
        )).json

        if not token: # or token.get('error'):
            return

        return token

    def oauth2callback(self, view_func):
        """
        Decorator for OAuth2 callback. Calls `GoogleLogin.login` then
        passes results to `view_func`.
        """

        @wraps(view_func)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            params = {}

            # Check sig
            if 'state' in request.args:
                params.update(**self.parse_state(request.args.get('state')))
                if params.pop('sig', None) != make_secure_token(**params):
                    return self.login_manager.unauthorized()

            code = request.args.get('code')

            # Web server flow
            if code:
                token = self.exchange_code(
                    code,
                    url_for(
                        request.endpoint,
                        _external=True,
                        _scheme=self.redirect_scheme,
                    ),
                )
                #received = get_access_token(token['access_token'])
                userinfo = self.get_userinfo(token['access_token'])
                params.update(token=token, userinfo=userinfo)

             # Browser flow
            else:
                if params:
                    params.update(dict(request.args.items()))
                else:
                    return '''
                    <script>
                      window.onload = function() {
                        location.href = '?' + window.location.hash.substr(1);
                      };
                    </script>
                    '''

            return view_func(**params)

        return decorated

    def user_loader(self, func):
        """
        Shortcut for `login_manager`'s `flask_login.LoginManager.user_loader`
        """
        self.login_manager.user_loader(func)
```

Please Note down there may be some disturbed code in def oauth2callback and the condition if code the line is
userinfo = self.get_userinfo(token['access_token'])

Here token['access_token'] produces the error names "TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'getitem'"

Please let me know how can I fix it

Comment: Hi, I seem to be getting the same error. Did you have any luck fixing this?

Comment: I did not use flask_googlelogin , as I also needed to include Facebook and Twitter SSO for my application. So I used flask_oauth login. My Repository is at this location [views.py](https://github.com/Chitrank-Dixit/InMyMind/blob/develop/src/application/views.py) please have a look at the code from line # 520 to 602

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug or api change.

In exchange_code

```
    token = requests.post(GOOGLE_OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL, data=dict(
        code=code,
        redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
        grant_type='authorization_code',
        client_id=self.client_id,
        client_secret=self.client_secret,
    )).json
```

token is now the json function. In newer versions of flask_googlelogin this is json().